# Regular Expression to wrap phrases between commas with carets (^)

Tags: google-sheets, regex

I have a Google Sheet with example information like this

```
Education, Conservation, Health, Human rights, Rural development, Poverty alleviation, Water and sanitation.
--------------------
Human rights, Democracy, Land reform, Entrepreneurship, ICT, Arts & culture
```

I need to quickly be able to wrap the phrases between the commas with a caret (`^`) in order for me to then import this sheet into a CRM.

Like this:

```
^Human rights^, ^Democracy^, ^Land reform^, ^Entrepreneurship^, ^ICT^, ^Arts & culture^
```

I've now read the [Google Sheets documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371415?hl=en) and looked and the [Example Regular Expressions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417). I've now looked at numerous ideas on the stack sites and not finding exactly what I need.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula works:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\s|^)([^,]*)","$1^$2^")
```

[image]

*Why* does it work?

- `(\s|^)` searches for a space or the beginning of the string
- `([^,]*)` searches for anything but a comma, as many times as possible
- The parentheses makes sure these 'capture groups' are available in the replace part; `$1` is the first capture group, `$2` is the second one.

A tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5pV58Z/1/) may help discovering what a regular expression does, and experiment a bit yourself.

Comment: thank you so much...saved a ton of time